# Format enum variables when they are called

Tags: java, enums

Is there any way to format the enum variables when they are called? I mean, If I have the next enum:

```
public enum Error{
IS_NULL("The variable {NAME_OF_VARIABLE} cannot be null.")
}
```

So, when I call it I want to replace {NAME_OF_VARIABLE} with the variable which is null. Ex: "The variable {phone_number} is null."

Now I use the next construction:

```
 enum Error{ 

    IS_NULL("The variable {%s} cannot be null.")

    public String errorMsg;
    }

    public String validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber){
    if(phoneNumber == null){
    return String.format(Error.IS_NULL.errorMsg, "phoneNumber")}
    return "OK"}
    }
}
```

It works fine, but it looks a bit messy.

Thank you!

Comment: Variables are not "called".

Comment: Thanks for correction! :D What would be the correct formulation then? :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your code doesn't compile and you can make use of a ternary operator to check if the `phoneNumber` is null or not.

Given the enum :

```
enum Error {

    IS_NULL("The variable {%s} cannot be null.");

    public String errorMsg;

    private Error(String errorMsg) {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

}
```

Validation method can be simplified to

```
public static String validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
  return phoneNumber == null ? String.format(Error.IS_NULL.errorMsg, "phoneNumber") : "OK";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `Optional` a little cleaner way of doing that could be:

```
public String validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(phoneNumber)
            .map(a -> String.format(Error.IS_NULL.getErrorMsg(), "phoneNumber"))
            .orElse("OK");
}
```